# How does WordPress Dynamically Generate Pages?

Tags: php, html, css, database, wordpress

I'm new to web building and programming and what not, but I'm trying to create a website with a lot of pages.  Note that this is pages not posts.  The pages will use the same layout, but the content will be different.  It's very inefficient to create the pages in Wordpress.  I was wondering where does Wordpress store the database that is used to generate the pages.  I figured I'll just add information to the data base - which would be much for efficient.

Any ideas on how to do this?  Or other ways to create many pages efficiently.  I would love to be able to work with Excel or some other text software, rather than the slow Wordpress platform.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

All content are saved to the wp_posts table in your WordPress database. whether its for pages or as posts. Databases are provided by your webhost. Edit: Excel is not a web authoring program, nor should it be used as one.

Comment: awesome, thanks!  That helps a lot to know it's in the wp-posts table

Answer (score 0):

You should put your header in header.php and footer in footer.php, and main content if it's not post type in page.php or you can make you custom page template, also if you are use page and not post, don't forget change it from settings

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Excel for your data. You can only use the Wordpress Database or external files.

As stated above, pages are stored in the posts table.

Since your data isn't actually dynamic, you should probably go ahead and create individual pages and *create a template to display the pages the way that you want them to  look.*

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/

For the record, you can use a single page to output different content. Most shopping carts, for example, are displayed using a page called 'Cart' (or something similar), but the output is different.  The Events Manager plugin outputs events to a page called 'Events'. This, however, is for truly dynamic data and not what you are looking for.